# Custom CellFactory adds new nodes

Tags: java, javafx

i have a weird bug and I cant find the appropriate solution.
I wanted to add a TreeTableView to my application that shows a task taxonomy.
Since the user is able to add tasks himself but these task have to be distinguishable from tasks already exsting I want them to be yellow in my TreeView. Therefore I added a custom CellFactory:

```
public class TaskLibrary extends AnchorPane {
    @FXML
    private TreeTableColumn<Task,String> mainColumn;
    @FXML
    private TreeTableView<Task> taskTreeTableView;

    public TaskLibrary(){
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../layout/TaskLibrary.fxml"));
            loader.setRoot(this);
            loader.setController(this);
            loader.load();
            mainColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().getValue().taskNameProperty());
            mainColumn.setCellFactory(param -> new TreeTableCell<Task,String>(){
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    Task listObject = this.getTreeTableRow().getItem();
                    if (listObject != null) {
                        if (item == null || empty) {
                            setText("");
                            setStyle("");
                        } else {
                            if (listObject.getIsDummy()) {
                                setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
                            }
                            setText(listObject.getTaskName());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }
        catch (IOException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void addNewTask(){
    }
    public void setColumnText(String text){
        mainColumn.setText(text);
    }

    public void enableDragAndDrop(){
        TaskTreeRowFactory fac = new TaskTreeRowFactory();
        taskTreeTableView.setRowFactory(fac::internalMoveFactory);
    }

    public TreeTableColumn<Task, String> getMainColumn() {
        return mainColumn;
    }

    public void setMainColumn(TreeTableColumn<Task, String> mainColumn) {
        this.mainColumn = mainColumn;
    }

    public TreeTableView<Task> getTaskTreeTableView() {
        return taskTreeTableView;
    }

    public void setTaskTreeTableView(TreeTableView<Task> taskTreeTableView) {
        this.taskTreeTableView = taskTreeTableView;
    }
}
```

Now there is this weird bug that expanding the last node in my treeview results in a new node:

[image]

is there something i missed?

Comment: If the cell is empty, `listObject` will be null, and your `updateItem` method doesn't do anything. So if a cell goes from non-empty to empty (e.g. when the user collapses a node in the tree), you don't remove the existing text. You need to remove the text (and clear the style) any time the cell is empty.

Comment: nice! That did it for me. Not very intuitive but i guess its more my lack of knowledge concerning JavaFX!

Comment: If it helps your intuition: your cells have three possible states of interest: empty, displaying dummy item, displaying non-dummy item. Your `updateItem()` method needs to handle a transition from any one of those states to any other, as well as simply changing to a different item in the same state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only manipulate the cell, if the row's item is not `null`. However if the row becomes empty the cell becomes empty too but `this.getTreeTableRow().getItem()` yields `null` and you don't modify the cell to look empty. You need to always clear the `text`/`style` when the cell becomes empty:

```
if (empty || item == null || listObject == null) {
    setText("");
    setStyle("");
} else {
    setStyle(listObject.getIsDummy() ? "-fx-background-color: yellow" : "");
    setText(listObject.getTaskName());
}
```